# how to check python bytes for dataframe string field?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a string that I would like to check for comparison.
df['ACCOUNTMANAGER'][0] this value has some special character that I cannot compare using string comparison. I tried to compare using bytes but it failed. I would like to check how the data is stored there for comparison. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Add some dummy data sample, and your approach will be really beneficial

Comment: There is already data but I need to know how it is encoded. Data is name that contains special characters. But when I print the string it removes them but when I compare it in if statement no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was being stored as utf-8 encoded format and now comparison works. I used for comparison byte b'\x8a' in if statement.